# What is the formula for choosing random number from a Excel Sheet Column?

Tags: random, excel-formula, numbers

Suppose a column has 100 entries but I want to choose only a certain percentage of a random number in that entry.

What is the formula for choosing a random number from an Excel Sheet Column? But, I choose only a certain percentage of number from that list?

Answer (score 0):

On top of my head and not tested because I am not on my computer but you can use RANDBETWEEN and INDEX combined to get the result. Let's say you have your row A1:A100:

```
=Index(A1:A100, RANDBETWEEN(1, COUNT(A1:A100)))
```

Comment: Regarding the percentage of number, I do not fully understand the question.

Comment: If that is the case can you mark the answer as answering your question